# How to keep the background of CollapsingToolbarLayout as the background of ToolBar even when collapsed

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My ToolBar position is always fixed at the top of the screen. The background image of the CollapsingToolbarLayout should always move behind the ToolBar. also at the same time, the toolbar should be transparent and should use the background of CollapsingToolbarLayout  as its background.

I made toolBar as transparent, my problem is, when CollapsingToolbarLayout is completely collapsed, my toolbar background is getting changed to color of "contentScrim". Why is this happening, how can i still keep the background of my CollapsingToolbarLayout as background of ToolBar event after completely collapsed. In my case the bottom of background of CollapsingToolbarLayout should be the background of ToolBar when its completely collapsed

This is the code i have currently

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" android:background="@drawable/profilepic">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"> <!-- android:color/transparent --><!--android:background="@color/primary"-->

            <!--Toolebar layout goed here-->

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by keeping the

```
    app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
```

in stead of

```
    app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
```